# node http doesnot have incomingMessage

Tags: node.js, express, http, webpack, node-modules

I'm trying to build an application using node server.

[image: http without IncomingMessage]

[image]

Http is without IncomingMessage making it to throw error.
Application was working properly with no changes it is getting crashed.
How could i fix this?
I'm quite new to node

Comment: Don't put screenshots in your questin, copy, paste your code directly using code block.

Comment: @MickaelB. Thank you for the suggestion.But, as it was an bundle.js file with huge code base so thought screenshot would be better.